# How to normalize the columns of a DataFrame using sklearn.preprocessing.normalize?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, normalize

is there a way to normalize the columns of a DataFrame using sklearn's normalize? I think that by default it normalizes rows

```
For example, if I had df:
A     B
1000  10
234   3
500   1.5
```

I would want to get the following:

```
A       B
1       1
0.234   0.3
0.5     0.15
```

Comment: I believe not all of the answers fit the question. Normalize is used to modify yhe sum of the absolute values to remain always up to 1 (L1). L2 option does the same but it is the the sum of the squares that sums up to 1.
if you want the highest number to be 1 then this is the best suggested solution
df / df.max()

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need `sklearn`?

Just use pandas:

```
>>> df / df.max()
       A     B
0  1.000  1.00
1  0.234  0.30
2  0.500  0.15
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using `div` after get the `max`

```
df.div(df.max(),1)
Out[456]: 
       A     B
0  1.000  1.00
1  0.234  0.30
2  0.500  0.15
```

Comment: What, it's always confusing to see who you are... okay, so now you're this person, nice answer tho, see mine too :-) i edited it

Answer (score 1):

`sklearn` defaults to normalize rows with the [`L2` normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm). Both of these arguments need to be changed for your desired normalization by the maximum value along columns:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing 

preprocessing.normalize(df, axis=0, norm='max')
#array([[1.   , 1.   ],
#       [0.234, 0.3  ],
#       [0.5  , 0.15 ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html)

> axis : 0 or 1, optional (1 by default) axis used to normalize the data
>   along. If 1, independently normalize each sample, otherwise (if 0)
>   normalize each feature.

So just change the axis. Having said that, `sklearn` is an overkill for this task. It can be achieved easily using pandas.